# Matrix free finite elements method

Tags: finite-element, gpu

I am Computer Scientist and now I am interested in matrix multiplication on GPUs. My research are focused on matrix free finite elements method where I multiply sparse matrix. Sparse matrix could multiply regular or matrix free. In general based on special coordinate function.
I have a few general question:
How popular is this method? Does any another name exist for this method?
I am also looking for books and article concentrate on finite element method especially matrix free multiplication and I consider about general books and article. Because many article based on rather complicated examples like conjugate gradient method or something different.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a discipline in academia, not about Academia itself.

Comment: What service on stack exchange you recommended for this question?

Comment: You may want to try Mathematics SE, Computer Science SE, Computational Science SE. Please do not cross-post i.e. please delete this one before you ask the same question on another SE.

Comment: Scicomp.se is definitely the right place for a question on this topic.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply. I dont' know why I cannot delete this question by myself. I don't have delete button.

Comment: I just flagged the moderator to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix-free finite elements are relatively well-known. For explicit methods for transient problems, this involves applying the finite element matrix using small reference matrices and geometry-specific transformations.

For implicit problems, this is usually done in conjunction with an iterative solver such as CG, GMRES, etc. Note that this typically also requires a preconditioner, many of which may not map well directly to GPUs. For nonlinear implicit problems, this may also be paired with a matrix-free approximation of the Jacobian in a linearization (see for example [Ben Kirk's thesis](http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~benkirk/dissertation.pdf) for an application of matrix-free implicit methods in CFD).

For GPU-specific implementations of explicit methods, there is ample literature on matrix-free implementations of finite element (specifically Discontinuous Galerkin) methods; see, for example, [Hesthaven/Warburton](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387720654) (not GPU specific, but implementation is similar) and [Klockner et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999109003647).  For some literature on the GPU implementation of matrix-free implicit solvers, see [Remacle, Gandham, Warburton](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05996), where they solve the heat equation using a two-grid overlapping additive Schwarz preconditioner.

Comment: This question also appears to be a duplicate.  Flagging.

Comment: Since this question will be deleted, would you copy your answer to the other version? It complements the other answer.